# ERROR in "controller_manager" when launching turtlebot4 and gazebo demo

Tags: ros-humble, turtlebot4

I've just noticed since last couple of days that gazebo (ignition fortress) is not able to normally start my turtlebot4 simulation anymore. After running the command below, the process starts, it manages to open the gazebo window for less than few seconds and then suddenly dies with an ERROR on "controller_manager" (it wasn't the case few days ago):

```
$ ros2 launch turtlebot4_ignition_bringup turtlebot4_ignition.launch.py world:=maze
```

My ROS installation runs from a docker container with ROS2 Humble + Gazebo Ignition Fortress and a Ubuntu22 as a host.

`launch.log`

```
1711822436.9016411 [INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/INF0429/.ros/log/2024-03-30-18-13-56-898009-kuntur-72
1711822436.9022210 [INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
1711822450.7100565 [INFO] [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1]: process started with pid [75]
1711822450.7237182 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-2]: process started with pid [77]
1711822450.7537355 [INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [80]
1711822450.7579319 [INFO] [joint_state_publisher-4]: process started with pid [82]
1711822450.7851520 [INFO] [robot_state_publisher-5]: process started with pid [85]
1711822450.8480246 [INFO] [static_transform_publisher-6]: process started with pid [87]
1711822450.8765490 [INFO] [create-7]: process started with pid [89]
1711822450.8772805 [INFO] [create-8]: process started with pid [93]
1711822450.8777590 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-9]: process started with pid [97]
1711822450.8781924 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-10]: process started with pid [108]
1711822450.8786054 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-11]: process started with pid [113]
1711822450.8789961 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-12]: process started with pid [126]
1711822450.8793781 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-13]: process started with pid [134]
1711822450.8797824 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-14]: process started with pid [136]
1711822450.9758987 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-15]: process started with pid [139]
1711822451.0525854 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-16]: process started with pid [142]
1711822451.0656426 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-17]: process started with pid [144]
1711822451.1093333 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-18]: process started with pid [146]
1711822451.1630969 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-19]: process started with pid [148]
1711822451.1915336 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-20]: process started with pid [150]
1711822451.2420616 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-21]: process started with pid [153]
1711822451.3141179 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-22]: process started with pid [155]
1711822451.3659084 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-23]: process started with pid [157]
1711822451.4465826 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-24]: process started with pid [159]
1711822451.5138648 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-25]: process started with pid [161]
1711822451.5406649 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-26]: process started with pid [163]
1711822451.6218066 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-27]: process started with pid [165]
1711822451.6900125 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-28]: process started with pid [167]
1711822451.6957748 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-29]: process started with pid [169]
1711822451.7229695 [INFO] [turtlebot4_node-30]: process started with pid [171]
1711822451.7237499 [INFO] [turtlebot4_ignition_hmi_node-31]: process started with pid [173]
1711822451.8017192 [INFO] [spawner-32]: process started with pid [175]
1711822451.8587728 [INFO] [hazards_vector_publisher-33]: process started with pid [177]
1711822451.9033241 [INFO] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34]: process started with pid [179]
1711822451.9349492 [INFO] [motion_control-35]: process started with pid [181]
1711822451.9868057 [INFO] [wheel_status_publisher-36]: process started with pid [183]
1711822452.0276473 [INFO] [mock_publisher-37]: process started with pid [187]
1711822452.0927806 [INFO] [robot_state-38]: process started with pid [194]
1711822452.2283120 [INFO] [kidnap_estimator_publisher-39]: process started with pid [197]
1711822452.3306820 [INFO] [ui_mgr-40]: process started with pid [205]
1711822452.4801762 [INFO] [pose_republisher_node-41]: process started with pid [225]
1711822452.5618014 [INFO] [sensors_node-42]: process started with pid [231]
1711822452.6406150 [INFO] [interface_buttons_node-43]: process started with pid [244]
1711822452.6518755 [INFO] [static_transform_publisher-44]: process started with pid [254]
1711822452.7167380 [INFO] [static_transform_publisher-45]: process started with pid [265]
1711822484.5939238 [ERROR] [spawner-32]: process has died [pid 175, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_state_broadcaster -c controller_manager --ros-args -r __ns:=/'].
1711822485.7631817 [INFO] [spawner-46]: process started with pid [819]
1711822493.3994575 [INFO] [create-7]: process has finished cleanly [pid 89]
1711822501.4443321 [INFO] [create-8]: process has finished cleanly [pid 93]
1711822512.2760990 [ERROR] [spawner-46]: process has died [pid 819, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner diffdrive_controller -c controller_manager --ros-args -r __ns:=/ --params-file /opt/ros/humble/share/irobot_create_control/config/control.yaml'].
1711822517.0150886 [INFO] [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1]: process has finished cleanly [pid 75]
1711822517.0179052 [INFO] [launch]: process[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] was required: shutting down launched system
1711822517.2647269 [INFO] [static_transform_publisher-45]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[static_transform_publisher-45]
1711822517.4098775 [INFO] [static_transform_publisher-44]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[static_transform_publisher-44]
1711822517.5655396 [INFO] [interface_buttons_node-43]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[interface_buttons_node-43]
1711822517.7437673 [INFO] [sensors_node-42]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[sensors_node-42]
1711822518.0783229 [INFO] [pose_republisher_node-41]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[pose_republisher_node-41]
1711822518.4398389 [INFO] [static_transform_publisher-45]: process has finished cleanly [pid 265]
1711822518.4626586 [INFO] [ui_mgr-40]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[ui_mgr-40]
1711822518.7533672 [INFO] [static_transform_publisher-44]: process has finished cleanly [pid 254]
1711822518.7842140 [INFO] [kidnap_estimator_publisher-39]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[kidnap_estimator_publisher-39]
1711822519.1805823 [INFO] [interface_buttons_node-43]: process has finished cleanly [pid 244]
1711822519.2124207 [INFO] [robot_state-38]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[robot_state-38]
1711822519.3089046 [INFO] [mock_publisher-37]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[mock_publisher-37]
1711822519.4062114 [INFO] [wheel_status_publisher-36]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[wheel_status_publisher-36]
1711822519.8053782 [INFO] [motion_control-35]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[motion_control-35]
1711822520.1777816 [INFO] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34]
1711822520.4720235 [INFO] [pose_republisher_node-41]: process has finished cleanly [pid 225]
1711822520.5599320 [INFO] [hazards_vector_publisher-33]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[hazards_vector_publisher-33]
1711822520.9473653 [INFO] [kidnap_estimator_publisher-39]: process has finished cleanly [pid 197]
1711822521.0221593 [INFO] [turtlebot4_ignition_hmi_node-31]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[turtlebot4_ignition_hmi_node-31]
1711822521.2063563 [INFO] [sensors_node-42]: process has finished cleanly [pid 231]
1711822521.2075901 [INFO] [mock_publisher-37]: process has finished cleanly [pid 187]
1711822521.2615283 [INFO] [turtlebot4_node-30]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[turtlebot4_node-30]
1711822521.3998418 [INFO] [robot_state-38]: process has finished cleanly [pid 194]
1711822521.4059527 [INFO] [wheel_status_publisher-36]: process has finished cleanly [pid 183]
1711822521.4106152 [INFO] [ui_mgr-40]: process has finished cleanly [pid 205]
1711822521.5487082 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-29]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-29]
1711822521.7263286 [INFO] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34]: process has finished cleanly [pid 179]
1711822521.8326762 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-28]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-28]
1711822522.1395254 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-27]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-27]
1711822522.2694030 [INFO] [turtlebot4_ignition_hmi_node-31]: process has finished cleanly [pid 173]
1711822522.2702587 [INFO] [hazards_vector_publisher-33]: process has finished cleanly [pid 177]
1711822522.3265352 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-26]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-26]
1711822522.4152164 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-29]: process has finished cleanly [pid 169]
1711822522.5441029 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-25]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-25]
1711822522.8914919 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-24]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-24]
1711822523.0322642 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-28]: process has finished cleanly [pid 167]
1711822523.1491172 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-23]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-23]
1711822523.2494111 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-26]: process has finished cleanly [pid 163]
1711822523.2503939 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-27]: process has finished cleanly [pid 165]
1711822523.3067799 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-22]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-22]
1711822523.3654010 [INFO] [motion_control-35]: process has finished cleanly [pid 181]
1711822523.3674371 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-25]: process has finished cleanly [pid 161]
1711822523.4509127 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-21]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-21]
1711822523.5726130 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-20]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-20]
1711822523.6272409 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-24]: process has finished cleanly [pid 159]
1711822523.6823595 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-19]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-19]
1711822523.7314639 [INFO] [turtlebot4_node-30]: process has finished cleanly [pid 171]
1711822523.7329187 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-23]: process has finished cleanly [pid 157]
1711822523.7345426 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-22]: process has finished cleanly [pid 155]
1711822523.7792265 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-18]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-18]
1711822523.8208406 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-21]: process has finished cleanly [pid 153]
1711822523.8773646 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-17]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-17]
1711822523.9205759 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-20]: process has finished cleanly [pid 150]
1711822523.9727046 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-16]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-16]
1711822524.0070658 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-19]: process has finished cleanly [pid 148]
1711822524.0523007 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-15]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-15]
1711822524.0855231 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-18]: process has finished cleanly [pid 146]
1711822524.1291699 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-14]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-14]
1711822524.1592953 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-17]: process has finished cleanly [pid 144]
1711822524.2109041 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-13]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-13]
1711822524.2410216 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-16]: process has finished cleanly [pid 142]
1711822524.2835624 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-12]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-12]
1711822524.3130305 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-15]: process has finished cleanly [pid 139]
1711822524.3539252 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-11]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-11]
1711822524.3789423 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-14]: process has finished cleanly [pid 136]
1711822524.4229546 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-10]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-10]
1711822524.4939942 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-9]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-9]
1711822524.5138328 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-13]: process has finished cleanly [pid 134]
1711822524.5639925 [INFO] [static_transform_publisher-6]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[static_transform_publisher-6]
1711822524.5763988 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-12]: process has finished cleanly [pid 126]
1711822524.6408360 [INFO] [robot_state_publisher-5]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[robot_state_publisher-5]
1711822524.6526124 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-11]: process has finished cleanly [pid 113]
1711822524.7228682 [INFO] [joint_state_publisher-4]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[joint_state_publisher-4]
1711822524.7313688 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-10]: process has finished cleanly [pid 108]
1711822524.7320843 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-9]: process has finished cleanly [pid 97]
1711822524.8077130 [INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[robot_state_publisher-3]
1711822524.9019382 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-2]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[parameter_bridge-2]
1711822524.9107461 [INFO] [static_transform_publisher-6]: process has finished cleanly [pid 87]
1711822524.9148319 [INFO] [robot_state_publisher-5]: process has finished cleanly [pid 85]
1711822524.9937837 [ERROR] [motion_control-35]: process[motion_control-35] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822524.9988828 [ERROR] [turtlebot4_node-30]: process[turtlebot4_node-30] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.0029657 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-29]: process[parameter_bridge-29] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.0092852 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-28]: process[parameter_bridge-28] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.0166981 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-27]: process[parameter_bridge-27] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.0232625 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-26]: process[parameter_bridge-26] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.0289578 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-25]: process[parameter_bridge-25] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.0333977 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-24]: process[parameter_bridge-24] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.0405881 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-23]: process[parameter_bridge-23] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.0452878 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-22]: process[parameter_bridge-22] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.0498199 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-21]: process[parameter_bridge-21] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.0554667 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-20]: process[parameter_bridge-20] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.0595286 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-19]: process[parameter_bridge-19] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.0660322 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-18]: process[parameter_bridge-18] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.0759311 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-17]: process[parameter_bridge-17] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.0846245 [INFO] [parameter_bridge-2]: process has finished cleanly [pid 77]
1711822525.0894001 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-16]: process[parameter_bridge-16] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.0980639 [INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process has finished cleanly [pid 80]
1711822525.1005213 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-15]: process[parameter_bridge-15] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.1053410 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-14]: process[parameter_bridge-14] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.1113122 [INFO] [joint_state_publisher-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 82]
1711822525.1152546 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-13]: process[parameter_bridge-13] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.1193659 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-12]: process[parameter_bridge-12] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.1234913 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-11]: process[parameter_bridge-11] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.1300869 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-10]: process[parameter_bridge-10] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.1381304 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-9]: process[parameter_bridge-9] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.1425490 [ERROR] [static_transform_publisher-6]: process[static_transform_publisher-6] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.1478469 [ERROR] [robot_state_publisher-5]: process[robot_state_publisher-5] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.1520007 [ERROR] [joint_state_publisher-4]: process[joint_state_publisher-4] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.1557901 [ERROR] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process[robot_state_publisher-3] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
1711822525.1601193 [ERROR] [parameter_bridge-2]: process[parameter_bridge-2] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
```